# While running Pact- Karma-Mocha framework, getting error - 'Can't find variable: Pact'

Tags: rest, karma-runner, pact

I am trying to get sample PACT JS framework (any variant) running for Contract testing. Initial plan is just to get the sample(s) provided get running & then later on make changes into End point and customise for our own purpose.

[PACT Foundation link: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/karma/mocha](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/karma/mocha)
Environment:

Win 7
Node: v8.11.4
dependencies installed:
    "@pact-foundation/karma-pact": {
      "version": "2.1.8",
  "@pact-foundation/pact-node": {
      "version": "6.19.11",

I am getting following error while trying to get it running.

[image]
**Command: karma start karma.conf.js**

```
C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha>karma start test/karma.conf.js
```

10 09 2018 09:53:34.544:ERROR [config]: File C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\test\karma.conf.js does not exist!

C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha>karma start karma.conf.js
[2018-09-10T08:53:42.384Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/16892 on W5167037:
    Creating Pact Server with options: 
    port = 1234,
    consumer = KarmaMochaConsumer,
    provider = KarmaMochaProvider,
    logLevel = DEBUG,
    log = C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\logs\pact.log,
    dir = C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\pacts,
    pactFileWriteMode = overwrite,
    ssl = false,
    cors = false,
    host = localhost
[2018-09-10T08:53:42.401Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/16892 on W5167037: Created 'standalone\win32-1.54.4\bin\pact-mock-service.bat service --port '1234' --consumer 'KarmaMochaConsumer
' --provider 'KarmaMochaProvider' --log-level 'DEBUG' --log 'C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\logs\pact.log' --pact_dir 'C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\pacts' --pact-file-write-mode 'overwri
te' --host 'localhost'' process with PID: 18912
10 09 2018 09:53:44.980:INFO [pact]: Pact Mock Server running on port: 1234
10 09 2018 09:53:45.054:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/dist-web/pact-web.js" does not match any file.
10 09 2018 09:53:45.092:INFO [karma]: Karma v3.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
10 09 2018 09:53:45.093:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS_without_security with unlimited concurrency
10 09 2018 09:53:45.101:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
10 09 2018 09:53:46.811:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket qMhVUJZzdDCD_YuKAAAA with id 47921548
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Client "before all" hook FAILED
        Can't find variable: Pact
        client-spec.js:10:32
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Client "after all" hook FAILED
        undefined is not an object (evaluating 'provider.finalize')
        client-spec.js:21:28
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 4 (2 FAILED) ERROR (0.013 secs / 0.001 secs)
[2018-09-10T08:53:46.985Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/16892 on W5167037: Removing all Pact servers.
[2018-09-10T08:53:46.986Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/16892 on W5167037: Removing Pact with PID: 18912

C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha>KARMA start
[2018-09-10T08:54:14.809Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/7492 on W5167037:
    Creating Pact Server with options: 
    port = 1234,
    consumer = KarmaMochaConsumer,
    provider = KarmaMochaProvider,
    logLevel = DEBUG,
    log = C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\logs\pact.log,
    dir = C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\pacts,
    pactFileWriteMode = overwrite,
    ssl = false,
    cors = false,
    host = localhost
[2018-09-10T08:54:14.823Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.19.11/7492 on W5167037: Created 'standalone\win32-1.54.4\bin\pact-mock-service.bat service --port '1234' --consumer 'KarmaMochaConsumer'
 --provider 'KarmaMochaProvider' --log-level 'DEBUG' --log 'C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\logs\pact.log' --pact_dir 'C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\pacts' --pact-file-write-mode 'overwrit
e' --host 'localhost'' process with PID: 2920
10 09 2018 09:54:17.376:INFO [pact]: Pact Mock Server running on port: 1234
10 09 2018 09:54:17.447:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/dist-web/pact-web.js" does not match any file.
10 09 2018 09:54:17.483:INFO [karma]: Karma v3.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
10 09 2018 09:54:17.484:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS_without_security with unlimited concurrency
10 09 2018 09:54:17.489:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
10 09 2018 09:54:19.243:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket rn-kwBRGhJbyUwvZAAAA with id 54614606
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Client "before all" hook FAILED
        Can't find variable: Pact
        client-spec.js:10:32
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Client "after all" hook FAILED
        undefined is not an object (evaluating 'provider.finalize')
        client-spec.js:21:28
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 4 (2 FAILED) ERROR (0.012 secs / 0 secs)

Kindly advise, Thanks a lot

Comment: Does C:\VarProjects\VanillaMocha\test\karma.conf.js  exist? The error would indicate that it doesn't. Best to post a reproducable github repository so that people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is failing because it's missing `pact-web`. You can see this in the error message you included:

```
Pattern "C:/dist-web/pact-web.js" does not match any file.
```

This is happening because you're using the example `karma.conf.js` outside the example repository without modification.

Quoting the relevant part of `karma.conf.js`:

```
// if you are using this example to setup your own project 
// load pact from the node_modules directory
'../../dist-web/pact-web.js',
// Example Using NPM package
// 'node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-web/pact-web.js',
```

Looking at your directory structure, commenting this line:

```
'../../dist-web/pact-web.js',
```

and uncommenting this line:

```
// 'node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-web/pact-web.js',
```

should solve your problem.

Note that you also need to ensure that `@pact-foundation/pact-web` is a dev-dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev '@pact-foundation/pact-web'
```